# Kendo UI notification modal or use window

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, notifications, window

So with kendo notifications, is there an option do to modal, disable everything until it's clicked, or should I be using the Kendo Window for that?

Answer (score 1):

Kendo UI notifications cannot be made modal. Window is definitely what you're after. You can make a modal window like this (Razor syntax):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("MyModal")
    .Title("My modal window")
    .Content(@<text>
        <h1>Greetings</h1>
        <p>Hello world!</p>
    </text>)
    .Height(300)
    .Width(600)
    .Modal(true)
)
```

The important part is the final line: `.Modal(true)`.